# how can i combine single and multi selection for a recyclerview in android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Iam developing a filter for search. And i have an custom recyclerview. I have multiple choice as default. But when last one selected i want to deselect other rows in recyclerview. How can i change the selection?

```java
public class HorizontalFilterItemsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalFilterItemsAdapter.HorizontalFilterItemsAdapterViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<StringModel> stringModelList;
    private HorizontalFilterItemClick horizontalFilterItemClick;
    private String dataType = "";
    private int selectedPos= 0;

    public HorizontalFilterItemsAdapter(Context context, List<StringModel> stringModelList, HorizontalFilterItemClick horizontalFilterItemClick, String dataType) {
        this.context = context;
        this.stringModelList = stringModelList;
        this.horizontalFilterItemClick = horizontalFilterItemClick;
        this.dataType = dataType;
    }

    public interface HorizontalFilterItemClick{
        void onHorizontalItemAddClick(int id, int position, String dataType);
        void onHorizontalItemRemoveClick(int id, int position, String dataType);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public HorizontalFilterItemsAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_horizontal_filter, parent, false);
        return new HorizontalFilterItemsAdapterViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HorizontalFilterItemsAdapterViewHolder holder, int position) {

        StringModel stringModel = stringModelList.get(position);

        holder.textView.setText(stringModel.stringData);

        getItemShape(position, holder.itemView);

        if (stringModel.isChecked) {
            holder.itemView.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(context.getColor(R.color.blue_kk_700)));
            holder.textView.setTextColor(context.getColor(R.color.white));
        }else{
            holder.textView.setTextColor(context.getColor(R.color.text_sub_header));

        }

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                selectedPos = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                if (!stringModel.isChecked){

                    stringModel.isChecked = true;
                    horizontalFilterItemClick.onHorizontalItemAddClick(stringModel.id, holder.getAdapterPosition(), dataType);
                    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(context.getColor(R.color.blue_kk_700));
                    holder.textView.setTextColor(context.getColor(R.color.white));

                }else{
                    stringModel.isChecked = false;

                    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(context.getColor(R.color.white));
                    holder.textView.setTextColor(context.getColor(R.color.text_sub_header));
                    horizontalFilterItemClick.onHorizontalItemRemoveClick(stringModel.id, holder.getAdapterPosition(), dataType);

                    getItemShape(holder.getAdapterPosition(), holder.itemView);

                }
            }
        });

    }

    @SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForDrawables")
    private void  getItemShape(int position, View view){
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                view.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_item_left_corner_radius));

                break;
            case 1:
            case 2:
            case 3:
            case 4:
            case 5:
                view.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_item_shape_rectangle));
                break;
            case 6:
                view.setBackground(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_item_right_corner_radius));
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return stringModelList == null ? 0 : stringModelList.size();
    }

    public class HorizontalFilterItemsAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView textView;

        public HorizontalFilterItemsAdapterViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        }
    }
```

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/button_click_background_selector"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextView.TextViewHeaderMedium14"
        android:translationZ="1dp"
        android:textColor="@color/custom_item_click_selector"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have custom backgrounds as well. Because of this reason, i can't deselect other rows. How can i deselect other rows when i click only last one? Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to have functionality that multiple items can be selected at a time right?
When a selected item is clicked again than it should de-selected all of the selected ones?

Comment: @mohammedahmed actually, i want to deselect all others when selecting first an last one. I tried notify data set change. but my custom view is not giving me right solution. i am using different backgrounds and custom selector color for click event. deselecting gives me different solutions every time. :(

Comment: With first and last you mean the index of item in the list ?

Comment: @mohammedahmed yes. recyclerview's first and last item. think like items: 1,2,3,4, select all and select nothing

Comment: Why don't you use select/de-select all toggle button?

Comment: @mohammedahmed toggle mean radio button?

Comment: Yeap, Radio buttons with radio group.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am using flutter anymore. So i don't need that anymore :) But i am going to use radio button instead ;)